# Is there a way to save only the username for a VPN in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, windows-registry, network-adapter

We add a IKEv2 VPN to our Windows 10 machines via a PowerShell script.

There's an option in the adapter settings to 'remember credentials' (image below) but it only works when you save both the password and the username so it will automatically log you in when pressing 'connect'. If you only enter a username, it will simply say it cannot connect because the credentials are wrong.

We want to be able to save only the username and have the user type their password in.

Is this possible? Maybe there's a registry key that can be added? I haven't been able to find anything yet.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Which VPN client are you using?

Comment: It depends on the client. In my client App (commercial) I just leave the password field blank.

Comment: It's a WatchGuard IKEv2 client, added as a WAN Miniport Network Adapter to Windows 10. When we hit connect, it just brings up the username/password entry field with no option to save anything. So we go to the settings to try to save it (Windows 10 VPN settings) but it only works if you have both password and username entered.